# Usage of the phrase "whether it is"

Tags: sentence-construction, subordinate-clauses

Many people use the phrase "whether it is" to introduce lists or alternatives at the beginning of sentences.

Can we also use "whether it is" in this way in other sentence positions such as in the following sentence:

> Unfortunately, human beings have limited ability to prevent an unhappy experience from happening in life, whether it is disease, injury, or the death of a family member.

Comment: Can't resist: "To be, or not to be, that is the question:
Whether 'tis Nobler in the mind to suffer
The Slings and Arrows of outrageous Fortune,
Or to take Arms against a Sea of troubles ..."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have used the phrase correctly.

Here are some examples of how it is used after other sentence elements.

> And, frankly, quite a lot has happened on our watch, **whether it is** the need to get Afghanistan right and draw down our troops, the huge fight we have had to try and clear up our banking systems and get our economies growing, while dealing with our deficits.

Date    2015 (150118)
Title   Interview With British Prime Minister David Cameron;
Source  CBS

> And, again, I would really like to see a president who would sincerely say, I want to work with Congress to address these problems, **whether it is** cyber-security or **whether it's** terrorism or the Ukraine or what China is doing.

Date    2015 (150120)
Title   PBS NewsHour for January 20, 2015
Source  PBS

> When you look at these activist groups, **whether it is** Black Lives Matter or occupy Wall Street or PETA, you're always going to get the idiotic fringe people in there, because there's no quality control.

Date    2015 (150825)
Title   THE FIVE for August 25, 2015
Source  Fox

> And, racism is the new modern day civil rights movement for these kids today, **whether it is** on a college campus or in the streets, where they do not feel safe.

Date    2015 (151109)
Title   President of University Of Missouri Resigns; Cell Phone Video Captures School`s Security Guard Being Pummeled By A Student; 18-Year-Old Student Faces Assault; School Officer Confronts Student Over A H
Source  CNN

> We look for places of common interest, **whether it is** around health or clean water or agriculture.

Date    2015
Publication information Jul2015, Vol. 59 Issue 6, p64-69. 6p. 3 Color Photographs.
Title   THE HIGH PRICE OF FAITH IN ACTION
Author  Morgan, Timothy C.;
Source  Christianity Today

> That's a sign of how quickly public sentiment has shifted on gay marriage, but it's also an indicator of how strongly many U.S. corporations feel compelled to weigh in on social issues, **whether it is** gay rights, the gender gap in pay or the fight over the Confederate flag.

Date    2015
Publication information 7/10/2015, Vol. 165 Issue 2, p26-33. 7p. 9 Color Photographs.
Title   CORPORATE REBEL YELL
Author  CADEI, EMILY;
Source  Newsweek Global

> This instruction goes through the API, **whether it is** DX11, DX12, or AMD's Mantle.

Date    2015
Publication information May2015, Vol. 33 Issue 5, p68-76. 9p.
Title   DirectX 12's potential performance leap is insane
Author  UNG, GORDON MAH;
Source  PC World

> This is true whether the smoke is from cigarettes, marijuana, or a forest fire, and **whether it is** primary smoke that you directly inhale or secondary smoke that you inhale after someone else has.

Date    2015
Publication information Mar/Apr2015, Vol. 287 Issue 2, p74-74. 1/2p.
Title   ASK DR. ZIPES
Author  Zipes, Douglas;
Source  Saturday Evening Post

> However, teachers have no control over what goes on at home, **whether it is** income, homework assistance, or diet and hygiene.

Date    2015 (150208)
Publication information PERSPECT; Pg. 2D
Title   The Open Forum Letters to the Editor
Source  Denver Post

> Evaluators often consider the reputation of the journal in which the article was published and **whether it is** an international, national, state, or local publication.

Date    2015
Publication information Fall2014, Vol. 81 Issue 1, p19-25. 7p.
Title   Out with the Old and In with the New: One University Department's Experience with Revisions of the Tenure-and-Promotion Policy
Author  Pyle, Elizabeth;
Source  Delta Kappa Gamma Bulletin

> There is much celebration of the efficiency savings and gains for work-life balance to be made from enabling your workforce to work remotely or on the go, **whether it is** from home, on a train, bus or in a coffee shop between meetings.

Date    2015
Publication information May2015, Vol. 67 Issue 5, p24-24. 1p.
Title   Mobiles and RSIs
Author  Christopherson, Robin;
Source  Occupational Health

> Meanwhile, the older and more knowing characters, notably the next-door Satanists Roman and Minnie Castevet, observe current events with cynical contempt, **whether it is** NASA programs or the Pope's visit.

Date    2014
Publication information Sep2014, Vol. 37 Issue 3, p314-330. 17p.
Title   Demonizing the Sixties: Possession Stories and the Crisis of Religious and Medical Authority in Post-Sixties American Popular Culture
Author  Quinlan, Sean M.;
Source  Journal of American Culture

> And he is confident that the chemical study of autocatalysis will play some part, **whether it is** the Kauffman-championed network variety or some more restricted type more like that used in many biochemical reactions in cells.

Date    2013
Publication information Mar2013, Vol. 63 Issue 3, p157-163. 7p.
Title   Life 2.0
Author  BEARDSLEY, TIMOTHY M.;
Source  BioScience

> He is a very busy horse that doesn't miss anything around him, and he seeks items to play with, **whether it is** a horse brush, a groom's jacket or a horse blanket within his reach.

Date    2012 (120616)
Publication information SPORTS
Title   A Suitcase Packed With Expectations, Stowed Away Until Next Year
Author  JULIE JUNE STEWART
Source  New York Times

All texts excerpted from search results on

Davies, Mark. (2008-) The Corpus of Contemporary American English: 520 million words, 1990-present. Available online at http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/. Accessed Feb 2, 2016.

Comment: Hi, Jim. Your answer is shorter than the comment above. Please delete this answer and put it as a comment. I am not the downvoter, but I don't think your post answers the question.

Comment: You are wasting my time. Just delete it. Is it too hard? If your answer stands, then, the question is proof-reading question, isn't it? Aren't you going to close vote it?

Comment: Jim's answer is, for me, TLDR, but is accurate. I would recommend a short para explaining the general usage, followed by a statement explicitly introducing the examples. I think the number of examples could be cut radically, and still make the point. Perhaps add a tip at the end "more examples at . . ." etc. Regardless, I'm giviing this an upvote as the best answer so far.

Comment: @Jim Reynold, You've explained the use of the phrase whether it's very convincingly.

Answer (score 0):

'whether' is a WH-connector used as conjuction or preposition. As a subordinating conjunction it introduces both noun clause and adverbial clause. It begins the first of two or more alternatives and sometimes repeated before the second or subsequent alternatives usually with the corelative 'or'. As for example:

• It matters little whether we go or stay.(sub NC)

•whether you like or not, you have to go to bed now.(Sub Adv.clause)

Similarly, whether can introduce phrases.

• whether to read or write, the teacher would decide.

'Whether it is' is an way of expressing alternatives. In the post it is effectively used as appositives to 'an unhappy experience'.