# "Whether it is" -- Is this right?

Tags: syntax, interrogatives

> Whether **it is** the happy childhood memory they both possess or **it is**
>   the intimate relationship derived from their elder generation, Tom and
>   Clancy are intersected intimately.

I am not sure whether this sentence is grammatically correct. Is the structure like "whether it is... it is" right?

Comment: It's not wrong, but you don't need the second "it is" and can be safely dropped in this case. Note that in an earlier era the subjunctive would have been used instead of the indicative: "Whether it **be** the happy childhood ..."

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81351/usage-of-the-phrase-whether-it-is

Answer (score -1):

Right now it's a little awkward because there is no *conjunction* connecting the conditions

> the happy childhood memory they both possess

and

> the intimate relationship derived from their elder generation

to the result:

> Tom and Clancy are intersected intimately.

You could replace **it is** with **because of**.  You can also omit the second use completely, as the **or** conjunction can separate the clauses without using "it is" or "because of" twice.

> Whether **because of** the happy childhood memory they both possess or the intimate relationship derived from their elder generation, Tom and Clancy are intersected intimately.

The conjunction's function is more obvious if you restructure the sentence (for clarity, I also removed some other modifiers that don't impact the overall grammatical structure).

> Tom and Clancy are intersected intimately **because of** the happy childhood memory **or** the intimate relationship

My modified sentence above is prosaic and not necessarily better, it's meant for illustrative purposes to show why a conjunction belongs in the sentence.

Having said all of this, "a little awkward" isn't always bad, and you could choose to leave your sentence alone if you believe you have valid stylistic reasons for doing so.  I would only recommend against it if this is formal writing.